# Saving associated models using transaction in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `User` model which has two fields `user_name` and `password`. 
`User` has two associations. One with `PersonalDetail` model and another with `UserRole` model.
I want to insert the data in these three table. If insertion fails It should not insert any data in any table.

For this I am using `sequelize transaction`. 
 But I am getting following error.

> TypeError: sequelize.transaction is not a function
>       at register (C:\Users\sujee\Desktop\onirique\users\src\services\register.js:21:15)
>       at router.post (C:\Users\sujee\Desktop\onirique\users\src\routes\register.js:16:32)

*Register.js*

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const User = require('../models').User
const Role = require('../models').Role
const PersonalDetail = require('../models').PersonalDetail
const UserRole = require('../models').UserRole



const register = async (req, res) => {
    if(req.body.role) {
             const role = await Role.findOne({ where: { role : req.body.role}})
             //serach for role if exist get the id or assign user role
             if(role) {
                role_id = role.id
             } else {
                 role_id = 0
             }
    } else {
        role_id = 0
    }
    sequelize.transaction( async transaction => {
        const createdUser = await User.create({
            user_name: req.body.user_name,
            password: req.body.password,
            PersonalDetail: {
                email: req.body.email,
                contact_number: req.body.contact_number
            },
            UserRole:{
                role_id: role_id
            }
        }, {
            include: [ PersonalDetail, UserRole ],
            transaction
        })
        return createdUser.dataValues
    })
}
module.exports = register
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in this case you do **not** require a transaction. This is because if creating `PersonalDetail` or `UserRole` fails then `User` will **not** be created.

As for the error you are getting. You cannot call sequelize.transaction() on the `sequelize module` itsself. This function should be called on the instance of your database connnection made using sequelize.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, { ...options })

Sequelize.transaction() // invalid, not a function
sequelize.transaction() // valid, because sequelize is an instance of Sequelize connected to db
```